# IMAP Exceptions in laravel, imap_open(): Couldnt open stream

Tags: laravel, server, stream, imap

I am facing this error, IMAP Exceptions in laravel, imap_open(): Couldnt open stream
Is this whm or cpanel error or laravel error, please clarify this, and let me know how to solve this,
take a look in screenshot as well.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with a socket tool or IMAP client that you can actually get to mail.icolauncher.io:143?  Usually SSL-secured IMAP is on port 993.

Comment: Also, mail.icolauncher.io doesn't appear to actually be a real hostname; if it's internal, you may need to do other configuration.

Comment: ok thanks, i am gonna try this method, and let you know if i again face the issue, thanks buddy